# TDictionary with index access in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I need a list that I can access by a key or by index. Is there any object in Delphi XE that already handles this for me?

I'm trying to use `TDictionary`, but there isn't an access by index.

I don't get the same order, using ToArray, for example:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var list: TDictionary<string, string>;
    arr: TArray<string>;
    b,a: Integer;
    value: string;
begin
  list := TDictionary<string, string>.Create();
  for a:=0 to 10 do
    begin
       b:=random(1000);
       value := 'index: ' + inttostr(a) + ' - value: ' + inttostr(b);
       list.Add(inttostr(b), value);
       memo1.Lines.Add(value);
    end;
  arr := list.Values.ToArray();
  for value in arr do
  begin
    memo2.Lines.Add(value);
  end;
end;
```

result:

```
index: 0 - value: 830
index: 1 - value: 265
index: 2 - value: 964
index: 3 - value: 765
index: 4 - value: 917
index: 5 - value: 826
index: 6 - value: 353
index: 7 - value: 431
index: 8 - value: 837
index: 9 - value: 373
index: 10 - value: 805
```

and

```
index: 7 - value: 431
index: 8 - value: 837
index: 9 - value: 373
index: 10 - value: 805
index: 4 - value: 917
index: 5 - value: 826
index: 0 - value: 830
index: 2 - value: 964
index: 3 - value: 765
index: 6 - value: 353
index: 1 - value: 265
```

Comment: Key-based containers are best implemented using storage that is not directly indexable, like hash tables. Which is exactly what `TDictionary` does. But you could use the `TDictionary.ToArray()` method to retrieve the items in order as an indexable array.

Comment: I tried these methods, but the order of items is not the same that was included.

Comment: `TDictionary.ToArray()` returns the items in the order that they are enumerated via `TDictionary.GetEnumerator()`. IIRC, `TDictionary` is a sorted container. If order is important, you need an unsorted container instead.

Comment: I just update an example. How can I unsort?

Comment: I was thinking of `list.ToArray()` instead of `list.Values.ToArray()`, but they use the same enumerator internally, so the ordering would be the same either way.  You can't rely on the order that `TDictionary` stores its key/value pairs internally.  And you can't unsort a `TDictionary` (unless you are storing sequential values, in which case you can sort the array that `ToArray()` returns, but that is not the case in your example).

Comment: You need something that stores values internally in insertion order to begin with, which is not `TDictionary`. You will probably have to create your own container, or find a 3rd party one.

Comment: @Remy I wouldn't say it was *sorted*. It is an unordered container, in that the order that items are added is not preserved.

Comment: @Beetlejuice You need an ordered dictionary. Do a search for one. If you can't find one, and I would not be surprised, then you can write you own class that wraps a list and a dictionary and maintains them in parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably have to create your own `T/IOrderedDictionary` class/interface

Here's what the interface might look like:

**[Based on Spring4D](https://bitbucket.org/sglienke/spring4d) - IDictionary/IList**

```
unit OrderedDictionary;

interface

uses
  Spring,
  Generics.Collections,
  Generics.Defaults,
  Spring.Collections,
  Spring.Collections.Dictionaries,
  Spring.Collections.Lists;

type
  IOrderedDictionary<K,V> = interface(IDictionary<K,V>)
    function Add(const item: TPair<K,V>): Integer;

  {$REGION 'Property Accessors'}
    function GetCapacity: Integer;
    function GetCount: Integer;
    function GetItem(index: Integer): TPair<K,V>;
    procedure SetCapacity(value: Integer);
    procedure SetCount(value: Integer);
    procedure SetItem(index: Integer; const item: TPair<K,V>);
  {$ENDREGION}

    /// <summary>
    ///   Inserts an item to the IList&lt;TPair<K,V>&gt; at the specified index.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">
    ///   The zero-based index at which item should be inserted.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="item">
    ///   The element to insert into the IList&lt;TPair<K,V>&gt;.
    /// </param>
    procedure Insert(index: Integer; const item: TPair<K,V>);
    procedure InsertRange(index: Integer; const values: array of TPair<K,V>); overload;
    procedure InsertRange(index: Integer; const collection: IEnumerable<TPair<K,V>>); overload;

    /// <summary>
    ///   Removes the item at the specified index.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">
    ///   The zero-based index of the item to remove.
    /// </param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">
    ///   <i>index</i> is not a valid index in the IList&lt;TPair<K,V>&gt;.
    /// </exception>
    procedure Delete(index: Integer);
    procedure DeleteRange(index, count: Integer);

    /// <summary>
    ///   Extracts the item at the specified index.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">
    ///   The zero-based index of the item to extract.
    /// </param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">
    ///   <i>index</i> is not a valid index in the IList&lt;TPair<K,V>&gt;.
    /// </exception>
    function ExtractAt(index: Integer): TPair<K,V>;
    function ExtractRange(index, count: Integer): TArray<TPair<K,V>>; overload;

    /// <summary>
    ///   Creates a new list that contains a range of the elements in the
    ///   original list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">
    ///   The zero-based index at which the range starts.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="count">
    ///   The number of elements in the range.
    /// </param>
    /// <remarks>
    ///   If the list contains reference types the elements in the returned
    ///   list point to the same instance as the elements in the original list.
    ///   Also if the original list is a <see cref="Spring.Collections.Lists|TObjectList&lt;TPair<K,V>&gt;" />
    ///    it still owns the objects.
    /// </remarks>
    function GetRange(index, count: Integer): IList<TPair<K,V>>;

    procedure Exchange(index1, index2: Integer);
    procedure Move(currentIndex, newIndex: Integer);

    procedure Reverse; overload;
    procedure Reverse(index, count: Integer); overload;

    procedure Sort; overload;
    procedure Sort(const comparer: IComparer<K>); overload;
    procedure Sort(const comparer: TComparison<K>); overload;
    procedure Sort(const comparer: IComparer<K>; index, count: Integer); overload;
    procedure Sort(const comparer: TComparison<K>; index, count: Integer); overload;

    /// <summary>
    ///   Determines the index of a specific item in the IList&lt;TPair<K,V>&gt;.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">
    ///   The element to locate in the IList&lt;TPair<K,V>&gt;.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    ///   The index of <i>item</i> if found in the list; otherwise, -1.
    /// </returns>
    /// <remarks>
    ///   If an element occurs multiple times in the list, the IndexOf method
    ///   always returns the first instance found.
    /// </remarks>
    function IndexOf(const Key: K): Integer; overload;
    function IndexOf(const Key: K; index: Integer): Integer; overload;
    function IndexOf(const Key: K; index, count: Integer): Integer; overload;

    function AsList: IList;

    /// <summary>
    ///   Returns the list as read-only list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    ///   This method will not perform a copy but will return the same instance
    ///   as IReadOnlyList&lt;TPair<K,V>&gt;.
    /// </remarks>
    function AsReadOnlyList: IReadOnlyList<TPair<K,V>>;
    procedure TrimExcess;

    property Capacity: Integer read GetCapacity write SetCapacity;
    property Count: Integer read GetCount write SetCount;
    property Items[index: Integer]: TPair<K,V> read GetItem write SetItem; default;
  end;
```

If you know (or can control) how the Dictionary stores its items, you might make the `List` a `TArray<Integer>` holding the index number of the storage that the dictionary uses or a `TArray<pointer to TPair<K,V>>`.
If `K` and `V` are small it might be better to just duplicate the list.

A better option might be to use a B+Tree to store your items, semantically it sits somewhere between the dictionary and the list.